# How to restrict a reverse SSH tunnel connection to the lowest possible access/commands?

Tags: windows, ssh, rdp, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

I have tried to set a reverse SSH tunnel access from a Windows client so i can RDP into his system without its firewall/NAT bugging me, but the problem I have is that when the user does a reverse SSH tunnel (doing -R option in ssh) to my linux system from windows, its basically like he is doing a SSH to me and can do commands and do whatever, but i only want this SSH connection to serve as a tunnel, so user can't do anything and tunnel being used only for doing RDP and bypassing the firewall

so how can i restrict the connected user from doing anything, and forcing this connection to only be used for the reverse RDP? because as of right now when he connects, he can type any command and has the  current access

and no i dont want to solve this by hide the CMD, i want to stop all the access from user.

as of right he is doing ssh -R ... in his cmd, and again, i don't want to solve this by just hiding the window, so don't want to add the -fN option either.

also i want to solution to be without any need to install a third-party software on the client, so i have to use the windows 10's build in features

Comment: Brainstorming, could you make the user he connect in with a different user with no file system permissions but with ssh permissions?

Comment: @Evan I cannot make another account